# audio doesnt get played on android 4.3 through webview which load url using android asset

Tags: android, html

I am not able to play the mp3 file from the android application which has a webview in which i am calling the html page

This is my main activity file

```
package com.example.dsspunjab;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        ImageButton button1, button2;
        ImageButton button3;
        WebView brows, brows1;
        final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
                button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                brows1=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                brows1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                brows1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/App1/index.html");

                button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                });



            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
        button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        brows=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        brows.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        brows.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/App/index.html");
        button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

this is the html code snippet where i am calling the mp3,
"

```
  <div class="modal-body">
   <!-- <img src="images/paddy_varieties/click-detail-punjab-basmati-2.png" data-elem="pinchzoomer" alt="img1"/> -->
   <audio msAudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" controls="controls"> 
    <source src="images/paddy_varieties/VN_Normal_1.mp3" class="mp3"/>

  </audio>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

"

I am able to play the video on the html page viewed through the web browser (google chrome) but not through the android application.

Comment: It didn't work, i tried putting mp4 instead of mp3

Comment: It is because you are not calling full url on android app "images/paddy_varieties/VN_Normal_1.mp3"